# File Association - Adobe Acrobat Reader (elementary OS - Loki)

Tags: release-loki

I am new to Linux. Moved from windows 10, Loving elementary OS. But need help with small things.

I installed Adobe Acrobat reader.

I selected a saved .pdf file -> Right Click -> choose properties -> selected Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Now I click on the file and I get an error.

[image: PFD File Association Error - Adobe Acrobat in elementary OS]

When I open Acrobat reader and try opening the PDF file from in there, it works.

Requesting help to fix this issue.

Thank you,
JagD

Comment: Can you share how you installed Adobe Acrobat. I too need Adobe Acrobat for some forms that only open in Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Acrobat Reader is not supported for Linux.

There’s a build in app for PDFs in elementary (In my opinion better than adobe reader).
You can also try other alternative apps - just google it ([first website that comes up](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/9-best-alternatives-to-adobe-reader-on-linux-ebookpdf-readers)). Calibre and Okular are pretty popular for example.